# IntelliJ IDEA - show handlebars syntax highlighting within PHP and HTML files

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, handlebars.js

In IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4, I have handlebars templates within PHP (and HTML) files. The syntax highlighting is not active for these templates. If I make a template its own file with the .handlebars extension, the syntax highlighting works properly, since the File Type of .handlebars is assigned to the Handlebars/Mustache plugin.

Is there a way for PHP and HTML files to "detect" handlebars' presence and appropriate proper syntax highlighting? (This would be analogous to how JS has proper syntax highlighting inside of HTML files.) I've read through the plugin docs, JetBrains' docs, and I've scoured SO. I'm wondering if I'm missing something very obvious.

Comment: See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106449 and linked issues.